# Why android application extension .apk? why not .jar or .jad?

Tags: android, file-extension, apk

Why google uses `.apk` for their application file extension name?? Why they didn't uses `.jar` , `.jad` or any another file extension??

The only reason I've come far as possible is

- `.apk` means Android Application Package.

I know they bundled the application package like every other compressor do. But still there must be several other reasons too.

`APK` files are ZIP file formatted packages based on the `JAR` file format. Why Google didn't used `.jar` then??

Please enlighten me on these Google chooses android application extension `.apk` only?? Why not any another file extension??

Comment: Because it's not a jad, or a jar.  It's just a ZIP file, and the Android designers arbitrarily chose APK.

Comment: @Lucifer hay brother!! Ping me via my user details page mentioned in stackoverflow. I tried yours but you haven't mention much.

Comment: @Lucifer: Oh good to see yeah brother!! Would you mind providing me your Fb username?? Cause chatting here create Flags!! :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why google uses .apk for their application file extension name?

They needed to use some file extension. Since an APK is not structured the same as a JAR or a JAD (different contents) it would be truly stupid for them to reuse those extensions. Hence, they went with something that was more distinctive.

Answer (score 3):

`.jar` stands for Java Archieve, `.jad` stands for Java Description same as `.apk` stands for Application Package

Android application contains the full package that's why it's extension is `.apk` which is short form of Application Package.